# How to configure Visual Studio Code C++ IntelliSense to do better autocomplete

Tags: c++, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I use Visual Studio Code, to write C++ code, and I use IntelliSense C++ extension, for "autocomplete", but it works very ugly for me.

If I type a variable, and hit the dot, it comes up a lot of suggestion, which are not connected to that type. I want it to show me only the valid/usable function of a type/class.

Comment: Intellisense is not that bad but also not perfect. You shouldn't expect too much. The intelligence is expected to be in front of screen not behind... ;-)

Comment: Yeah, thats right, the real intelligence is in front of the screen, but I saw better working autocomplete in other IDE (Eclipse, CLion). I dont know they are Intellisense also...